# parented cube wont move unless data values entered into location fields?

Tags: parent

The cube is parented and will only move when I enter values into the location fields but not when I try to move it with a mouse?

the file
[image]

Comment: You have locks set. Click on the bright blue buttons beside the transform fields to unlock them.

Comment: Yes, as Anthony Forwood said you probably have transform locks active. To unlock just press the key lock icons by the side of the transform location buttons in the toolshelf. Just have in mind that the buttons may not be bright blue depending on the current theme used.